# Ruby on Rails MySQL select page undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've recently migrated my webpage internally at my company to Ruby on Rails, and I've got mysql setup and reading, but I'm currently trying to setup a webpage, and display some basic information I am getting this undefined method `each' error. If anyone can lend me a hand it would be useful, I feel like I'm just missing something, and once I get this sorted I can stuck plugging away!

```
NoMethodError in Index#toolkit

Showing /rhel5pdi/apollo/var/env/BlackMesaRails/rails-root/app/views/index/toolkit.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #9):

6:              <h3>Toolkit</h3>
7:          </div>
8:          <p>
9:           <% @toolkit_urls.each do |toolkit| %>
10:                           <div class="page-header"><h3><%= raw toolkit.name %></h3></div>
11:                           <p><%= raw toolkit.url %></p>
12:                         <% end %>
Rails.root: /rhel5pdi/apollo/var/env/BlackMesaRails/rails-root

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/index/toolkit.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_index_toolkit_html_erb___2469700212325674377_127789780760'
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

I'll display my Model, view, and controller

**index_controller.rb**

```
    class IndexController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :initialize_remote_user
  def index
  end
  def toolkit
    @toolkit_urls = HelpToolkit.order(:name)
  end

end
```

**toolkit.html.erb**

```
<body>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="well sales-pitch">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h3>Toolkit</h3>
            </div>
            <p>
             <% @toolkit_urls.each do |toolkit| %>
                          <div class="page-header"><h3><%= raw toolkit.name %></h3></div>
                          <p><%= raw toolkit.url %></p>
                        <% end %>
</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**help_toolkit.rb (Model)**

```
class HelpToolkit < ActiveRecord::Base #class beginning
  attr_accessible :id, :url, :name
end
```

Comment: `Toolkit.select('url, name').from('lambda.help_toolkit').order('name')` should be just `Toolkit.order(:name)`. However this does not justify the error, it seems that you are triggering wrong action. Can you post the entire error screen content?

Comment: What does your config/routes.rb look like? How are you creating the custom route index#toolkit

Comment: BroiSatse - I've updated my original post with the full error message

ReggieB - Here is my routes for this file.
get "/toolkit" => "index#toolkit"

Very simple, works just fine without the MySQL select statement, but with has issues.

Comment: And what is the result of the query when you run in in rails console?

Comment: @BroiSatse - Changed query, to HelpToolkit.All to simplify things. Also changed model to closer resemble the mysql database table. The table is called help_toolkit, hence named it HelpToolkit. I updated question with additions, I still am receiving the error. Thanks!

Comment: If you arw using active record. The convention for naming models and tables is HelpToolkit / help_toolkits.  But if active record can't find your table, it will complain, so I still don't see why you get nil instead of an error when you call the query.

Comment: Hmm, odd. The code/page works when It's on my local:3000, but when I push it to live is when the error occurs... GREAT! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected my issue. The Model was looking for the plural table name, so it was looking for help_toolkits, so what I had to do was modify the environment.rb file to make table_pluralization = false. Doing this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it looks like you are not assigning the variable in the index method:

```
def index
  #assign variable here! Or call the toolkit method here
end
def toolkit
  @toolkit_urls = Toolkit.select('url, name').from('test.help_toolkit').order('name')
end
```

Edit:

Nope sorry. Misread the action name....

Comment: Well, index, and toolkit are both in the index view. and toolkit is it's own page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this

```
def toolkit
  @toolkit_urls = HelpToolkit.All
end
```

should be

```
def toolkit
  @toolkit_urls = HelpToolkit.all
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I caught that as well. Odd, in :3000 I have no issues, but when I push to live is when the error arrives... Hmm

Comment: @Spartacus38 Please accept my answer if it worked for you :)